# Enter text from text box into combo box vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, combobox, textbox

I have two form, A and B.

On `FORM A` user will select a country code from `combobox` and it will then be saved to DB.

On `FORM B` a `textbox` shows the country code that was saved to the database earlier.

I want to change the country code in `FORM B` when `edit` is selected.

How to change:
1. the textbox will first be hidden
2. a combobox with all the country codes will be shown with selected value equals to the hidden textbox value.

I have tried putting the info into the combobox like the textboxes straight from the database when it is blank, e.g:

```vb
cbCountryCode.Text = CStr(dataTable.Rows(0).Item(2))
```

but this does not work. I also need to keep the country codes in the combobox as the user will need to change the country code if it's wrong. Is there a way of doing this? I have a work around where I don't let the user update the info if the combobox is blank, but I want the country code to be already there so that the user does not have to select a country code again if it is not wrong. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

datatable.Rows(0).Item(2) 
holds a country code, for example, `Ireland (+353), United Kingdom (+44) or U.S.A. (1)`.
This is the code I have for calling the information from the database:

```vb
sqlVisitorDetails = "SELECT * FROM visitorDetails WHERE idNumber=@idNumber"

sqlCon.Open()
sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlVisitorDetails, sqlCon)
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", txtIdNumber.Text)

dtVisitorDetails = loadDtVisitorDetails()

txtFirstName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(1))
txtLastName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(2))
txtContactNumber.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(3))
txtCountryCode.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(4))
txtAddress.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(5))
```

The country code (e.g. 'Ireland (+353)') is stored in dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(4) and this is put into the text box txtCountryCode. 
When edit is clicked on the form, the text box txtCountryCode is hidden and the combobox cbCountryCode is visible (before edit is clicked txtCountryCode is shown and cbCountryCode is hidden). I then want the country code (in this case 'Ireland (+353)') to be shown in the cbCountryCode combo box. At the moment when the combobox is shown it is blank and the user has to choose a country code again, even if it's right. I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: You can't have it both ways @chinz!  Half the time the questions are short and meaningless, and now you're complaining there's too much information!  It _is_ a bit long.. but still.. :))

Comment: @Grim, I dont mind reading a long question. but not all in one line perhaps? =]

Comment: Can you suggest a better way of asking this question with all the information in it @chinz

Comment: How are you filling the combobox?

Comment: In the properties of the combobox in 'Items' I have copied and pasted a list of country codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the best i can understand from your question.

```
cbCountryCode.Text = CStr(dataTable.Rows(0).Item(2))
```

will not work if the `DropDownStyle` in the properties is set to `DropDownList`, change it to `DropDown` instead(if its not).

And to this:
`I also need to keep the country codes in the combobox as the user will need to change the country code if it's wrong.`

you have to bind the data to the ComboBox to make it work.

EDIT:
If possible, use `ColumnName` instead of `Index` for getting a data from datatable. Since you're selecting all record from your database, your may not know when then index would change(when a column is added or deleted from DB)

```
cbCountryCode.Text = CStr(dataTable.Rows(0).Item("CountryCodeColumn"))
```

Comment: Thank you @chinz, that solved my problem. I changed DropDownList to DropDown, used cbCountryCode.Text = CStr(dataTable.Rows(0).Item(2)) and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, check the updated answer for a minor suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```vb
cbCountryCode.SelectedItem = CStr(dataTable.Rows(0).Item(2))
```

The `.Text` property is the currently selected text in the combo, not the currently selected item.

**EDIT: (version 3!)**

This definitely works!  Create a new project, with a new WinForms project and Form1, etc.  Add a button (btnTest) and a combobox (cboTest) and paste this code in;

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Add some items
    cboTest.Items.Add("U.S.A (+1)")
    cboTest.Items.Add("Ireland (+353)")
    cboTest.Items.Add("U.K. (+44)")

    ' Select the first item
    cboTest.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnTest_Click() Handles btnTest.Click
    ' Select the UK entry
    cboTest.SelectedIndex = cboTest.FindString("U.K.")
End Sub
```

And I hate to have to say it, but it works like a charm!  I've tested it with the combobox set to `DropDown` AND to `DropDownList` and the result is the same.  Please check you have the right data going into and out of your routines from the dataTable/Row/Item you are using!!

Comment: It's still coming up blank. Sorry for the second comment but I can't edit my first one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.FindStringExact`?

Comment: That depends on the context.  I don't know what the contents of the combo actually are...

Comment: Thanks again Grim, but that didn't work and neither did     .FindStringExact @Pradeep Kumar, I am editing the question now to answer your question Grim

Comment: @Coder92 - please see my corrected answer - my mistake, doing 1001 things at once like usual - it's the `.SelectedIndex` you need to set, because `.FindString` returns an Integer, not an Item/Object!!

Comment: cbCountryCode.FindString = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(6))

Comment: Is the above comment what you mean? If it is it doesn't work either, it's throwing an error saying "Overloaded resolution failed because no accessible 'FindString' accepts this number of arguments"

Comment: Sorry @Grim, just saw the second edit there but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```vb
cbCountryCode.ClearSelection()

cbCountryCode.SelectedIndex = cbCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(cbCountryCode.Items.FindByText(datatable.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply in combo box property - change these two fields:
[Here is how you add items in Combo Box via Text Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqByV.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try simple:

`comboBox.Items.Add("Item 1");`

Comment: How is adding a new item going to change what's selected in the combo?!!?

Comment: I only saw @Grim's comment after I sent my comment, I realised then why it didn't work.

Comment: "Enter text from text box into combo box vb.net" this was your question. So I'm trying to show who to add a new item in your ComboBox.

Comment: We've already commented that it's a fairly long question, but nevertheless, you should still read it!